# Sorting a list but keeping the order of duplicates

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates

I have to sort all my items according to their expiry date (YYYYMMDD), the sooner the expiry date, the closer to the end of the list the item should be (the reason for `reverse=True`) and when the expiry date is the same, i should have the one that was added sooner closer to the end (FIFO). I tried using the `sorted()` function, and as you can see here, the result is different from my desired result.

```
a = "20220202", "ACME Rice Ltd."
b = "20220315", "UniCORN & co."
c = "20771023", "RICE Unlimited"
d = "20220921", "G. P. a C."
e = "20220202", "Theorem's Rice"

lst = [a, b, c, d, e]

lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])

lst_output = [c, d, b, a, e]
lst_desired_output = [c, d, b, e, a]
```

Is there any way to use the `sorted()` function here, or do i have to do something completely else?

Comment: Now try with `lst = [e, d, c, b, a]`. You ask function to sort list in reversed order so it does exactly what you want. Basically it will iterate from start to end if `reverse=True`, so if you want to keep order - use reversed list.

Comment: @OlvinRoght yeah that would be the easy way to do it, however i am not the one that decides which "item" will be stored first - i dont decide the order in which the items are sorted in the list. thats my main issue

Comment: `sorted()` is stable, it keeps the original order. But when you use `reverse=True`, this means that it uses the reverse order of the originals.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i understand that, thats why i'm asking if theres a way to not-reverse the duplicates. thanks so much for your input tho! i may have not correctly understood the reverse in sorted until now. helpful:)

Comment: @Petra, pass `lst[::-1]` or `reversed(lst)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort the reversed list, thus the last item will always be first:

```
sorted(reversed(lst), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

or sort in order and reverse:

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])[::-1]
# list(reversed(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])))
```

output:

```
[('20771023', 'RICE Unlimited'),
 ('20220921', 'G. P. a C.'),
 ('20220315', 'UniCORN & co.'),
 ('20220202', "Theorem's Rice"),
 ('20220202', 'ACME Rice Ltd.')]
```